# How to use Unique between multiple columns, without counting certain delimiters?

Tags: excel

Say I have a list like the one below. I'd like to generate another list, containing each unique artist once. I am using a mac (no `FILTERXML()`)

[image: e]

Is there a way to modify the unique function (or any other) in order to produce the one list below automatically (highlighting still done manually)? The "N/A"s can be replaced with empty spaces (like some of the boxes where I didn't put it in).

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate on the criteria you want to apply to the list.

Comment: I'd like to generate another list, containing each unique artist once.

Comment: Have you tried using Excel's Filter to extract unique values or use the *Remove Duplicates* function?

Comment: I'd like an auto-updating formula for the second list given that the first one is subject to augmentation (it is added to often)

Comment: See if this helps .. https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-unique-function ... and if you want it to be dynamic range, you can mention the table column name

Comment: It's not in depth enough (or I'm not sharp enough) for me to figure out how to do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
*After some discussion in the chat room, revealing that @AlecAlameddine is getting error messages with formulas that work elsewhere, it seems likely that the size of the data, along with the required `space` substitutions, is resulting in formula terms that are longer than `32,767` which is a limitation of, if I recall correctly, not only `TEXTJOIN` but also `SUBSTITUTE`*

To create a dynamic function to handle this we will need to use VBA. *I wrote it as a function as you have indicated you prefer it to dynamically update*

The UDF is not constrained by the same size limitations as are worksheet formulas.

It will return a vertical array which will `Spill Down` as any dynamic array.

- To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), <kbd>alt-F11</kbd> opens the Visual Basic Editor.
- Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
- Then, from the top menu, select Insert/Module and
  paste the code below into the window that opens.

```
Option Explicit
Function Singers(rg As Range) As Variant()
    Dim COL As Collection
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim v, w, x, I As Long

Set COL = New Collection

'Create array for the values
vSrc = rg

'Filter uniques into a collection object

On Error Resume Next 'allows collection to skip any duplicates without errors
For Each v In vSrc
    
    'split the "+"'s
    w = Split(v, "+")
    
    'Trim & Remove the "N/A"'s and add to dictionary
    For Each x In w
        If Trim(x) <> "N/A" Then
            COL.Add Trim(x), Trim(x)
        End If
    Next x
Next v

On Error GoTo 0

'create results array
ReDim vRes(1 To COL.Count, 1 To 1)
For I = 1 To COL.Count
    vRes(I, 1) = COL(I)
Next I

'Transfer array to output of the function
Singers = vRes

End Function
```

- To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like `=singers(Songs)` in some cell

---

#### Previous formulas that will not work with large data but will work with small data

You can do this with the `TEXTJOIN` and `FILTERXML` functions.  No VBA needed:

`TEXTJOIN` will create a single string from the multicolumn array.
`FILTERXML` will return each unique node, and also filter out the `N/A`'s

```
=UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,  SUBSTITUTE(myRange,"+","</s><s>"))&"</s></t>","//s[not(.='N/A')]"))
```

From your question I'm not sure if you just want to filter out the `N/A`'s, or actually replace them with blanks.

**Note:**  *Although we can create an `XPATH` argument to return a unique list of nodes, because of the leading/trailing spaces when we replace the `+`, they won't be seen as unique by `FILTERXML`. Since the return value from `FILTERXML` is trimmed of those, we can apply the `UNIQUE` function at that point*

[image]

If you have a MAC and do not have the `FILTERXML` function, you can use this:

```
=UNIQUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(REPT(" ",99),TRUE,myRange),"+",REPT(" ",99)),"N/A",""),SEQ_99,99)))
```

where `SEQ_99` is a named formula and refers to:

```
=IF(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,99,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,99,1))-1)*99)
```

This formula replaces the `N/A` with a blank.

If you prefer to not show the blank, then remove the N/A first:

```
=UNIQUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(REPT(" ",99),TRUE,SUBSTITUTE(myRange,"N/A","")),"+",REPT(" ",99)),"N/A",""),SEQ_99,99)))
```

**Note:** As written, the items are returned `row by row`. If you prefer to see them returned `column by column`, then merely transpose the range:    replace `myRange` with TRANSPOSE(myRange)`

Comment: This seems perfect. Unfortunately I am using a mac and `FILTERXML()` is not available...

Comment: @AlecAlameddine Do you have `TEXTJOIN` on the MAC?

Comment: Yes, textjoin is availible

Comment: @AlecAlameddine Edit posted

Comment: What would be the exact formula if my data is in C, D and E?

Comment: @AlecAlameddine Change `myRange` to refer to your data range.

Comment: I dont haveth to change A:A and B:B references in seq_99?

Comment: @AlecAlameddine Leave that **exactly** as I posted it.  I did not post any `B:B` sequence. Where did you get that from?

Comment: =UNIQUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(REPT(" ",999),TRUE,Songs[@[Lead Artist]:[Additional Credit]]),"+",REPT(" ",999)),"N/A",""),IF(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,999,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,999,1))-1)*999),999))) gives me a spill error

Comment: there is no data below obstructing it

Comment: @AlecAlameddine Is this formula within a table?  You can't use dynamic arrays in a table.  Also, you need to remove the `@`

Comment: =UNIQUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(REPT(" ",999),TRUE,SUBSTITUTE('Song Ranking'!C:E,"N/A","")),"+",REPT(" ",999)),"N/A",""),IF(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,999,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,999,1))-1)*999),999))) out of a table gives me a value error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210056/discussion-between-ron-rosenfeld-and-alec-alameddine).

Answer (score 0):

As you are aware, if you use `UNIQUE()` on a block of cells, it returns another spill-down block rather than a single spill-down column.

This tiny User Defined Function:

```
Public Function Block2Column(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim arr, OneCol(), cnt As Long, a

    arr = rng.Value
    cnt = rng.Count
    ReDim OneCol(1 To cnt, 1 To 1)
    i = 1

    For Each a In arr
        OneCol(i, 1) = a
        i = i + 1
    Next a
    Block2Column = OneCol
End Function
```

will return a single-column spill-down from a block of cells.  Here is an example of its use:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To further process the list, use `FILTER()`.  This way you can remove the **+** records, the **N/A** records, and any blanks. Like:

```
FILTER(UNIQUE(Block2Col()))
```

Comment: Perfect, now I just need a way to ignore the pluses and look at only each artist

Comment: @AlecAlameddine See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Turns out my "clever" formulas won't work on large data, so a VBA solution would be better.  I ***think*** that is due to the 32,767 cell character length limit.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  I wish that there was a native function that would convert an array of data into a single-column spill-down.  Then VBA could be avoided.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent If the data array is not too large, so that the resultant text string is <= 32,767, you can do that with a combination of `TEXTJOIN` and `FILTERXML`.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  I like you MAC formula the best!  I took it, discarded the `SUBSTTUTE()`s and ended up with a nice, general, block to spill-down formula! ...................thanks!